# SQL Query, Show only single addresses on orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure I'm missing something easy here. I have a query that returns a dataset that looks like this:

```
**OrderNum     Address**
  12345        1405 W Hollywood
  12346        1555 3rd Ave
  22334        PO Box 1467
  22334        1327 14th Ln S.
```

What I'd like is to now count those up to where I only see one address per Order, or if there is more than one, just display 'Multiple' like this

```
**OrderNum     Address**
  12345        1405 W Hollywood
  12346        1555 3rd Ave
  22334        Multiple
```

If I try doing it off a case like 'case when count(OrderNum) > 1 ...' then I have to group by address and it doesn't work. Other ideas? My brain is stuck on this so I need a nudge. Thanks!

Comment: Is Address stored in a separate table to OrderNum? Can you post the DDL of your tables?

Comment: Do any of below answers work for you?

Comment: Yeah two of them got me what i was looking for. Thanks all

Comment: Ok great - sorry mine was a little off but you saw what I was going for

Comment: I did and I haven't had a lot of experience using Having so I still appreciated the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ordernum, 
       case when count(*) > 1 
            then 'multiple'
            else max(address)
       end as address
from your_table
group by ordernum
```

You need to aggregate all columns that you don't group by. I guess you did not use `max(address)` or something similar.

Comment: So simple, I was so close ha. That worked. I'll just go get my coffee now.

Answer (score 1):

Use *window* function:

```
select distinct ordernum, 
      (case when AddrCount > 1 then 'Multiple' else address end) as address
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by OrderNum) as AddrCount
      from table 
     ) t;
```